# Script Shell - How to print out echo if two conditions are met? (Only numbers, exakt 2 conditions)

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, script

I'm new to shell scripting and are trying to learn the basics. I'm launching a script using the terminal such as "./scriptgoeshere.sh Argument1 Argument2".

I want the script to print some echo, "Hello World" is probably the best one to use, but I only want it to print out hello world if there are: Exactly two arguments, and those arguments have to consist solely of numbers. For example:

./scriptgoeshere.sh 1523 9643
./scriptgoeshere.sh 7 96
Should work, however;
./scriptgoeshere.sh 594 arg 
Should NOT work, this is the script I have at the moment but it doesn't work, Ive tried figuring this out the entire day but cant seem to nail it, I even tried if/elif/else where I had it check if there are 2 inputs in the if part, and if they are both numbers in elif before continuing.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && [ "$@" -eq ^[0-9] ]; 
then
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt 3 ]
    do
        echo "Hello World!"
        sleep 5
        i=$((i+1))
    done
else
echo "Need two arguments and only numbers will be accepted, such as ./scriptgoeshere 153 251"

fi
```

It blocks the hello world loop until I put in 2 arguments, but it doesnt matter if they are numbers or text, and I get an error then:
"./scriptgoeshere.sh: line 2: [: ^[0-9]: integer expression expected".
I get that error even if I write ./scriptgoeshere.sh 123 123 in the terminal to launch it. I prefer to not solve it by variables as I want to figure out the arguments when launching the actual script.

This is doing my head in!

This is what I started with to make it check if there are exactly 2 arguments and it works, I just wanna add a small fix to it so those 2 arguments HAS to be numbers. I don't get why it seems to be so hard.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ];
then
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt 3 ]
    do
        echo "Hello World!"
        sleep 1
        i=$((i+1))
    done
else
echo "Need two argument, only numbers accepted"

fi
```

Edit: I solved it. I had worked so close.. I just needed to add extra [] to the number part of the if-string. Anyone knows why it needs to be written as [[ "$@" -eq ^[0-9] ]] while the first part can be written with just one [] ?

Comment: Sigh… If you keep changing your code I will never finish my answer that tries to elaborate your mistakes, reveal pitfalls and such.

Comment: Haha I'm sorry! I've been working through a virtualbox and my keyboard inputs have been fucked and I haven't gotten around to fixing it yet, can't type []$@ for instance which means I've had it all copied over from the VMBox. Noticed a few things went missing and such, I updated it 23mins ago when I managed to solve it, did it previously when the code didnt copy-paste correctly.

I managed to solve it with if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && [[ "$@"  =~ ^[0-9] ]];"

Comment: And you even edited your comment after I read it! :/ And it says your solution is `[[ "$@" =~ ^[0-9] ]]` but the question body claims it is `[[ "$@" -eq ^[0-9] ]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first `[ "$#" -eq ^[0-9] ]` or `[ "$@" -eq ^[0-9] ]` (the question was edited while I was composing my answer…). From the context I think you want to test if the parameter is a number.

- `$#` is always a number, the number of positional parameters in decimal. You want to test two positional parameters: `$1` and `$2`.
- `[` is a command (`[ whatever ]` is equivalent to `test whatever`). It may be a shell builtin but syntactically it's like `ls` or `man`. Words that follow (including `]`) are parsed by the shell like any words that follow a command: shell expands them (e.g. `$#` becomes a number), removes quotes; eventually they become parameters to `[`. One of these expansions is filename expansion where various patterns are matched against existing filenames (filename expansion, globbing). Unquoted `^[0-9]` may expand to `^2 ^5` if these files exist. If there is no match or if you disable the feature `^[0-9]` will get to `[` (as one of its arguments) literally. It looks like a pattern but `[` doesn't support pattern matching anyway.
- `-eq` requires the previous and the next argument to be integers. `$#` expands to an integer for sure. There is no way for `^[0-9]` to expand to a number in this context.
- Double-quoted `$@` is special, it can expand to multiple words ("fields" in terms of POSIX) despite being quoted. Usually we quote to prevent word splitting: `"$foo"` expands to one word even if the value contains spaces and such. `"$@"` expands like `"$1" "$2" …`, its double-quotes prevent `$1` to expand to multiple words (and separately `$2` and so on). In this fragment:

  ```
  [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && [ "$@" -eq ^[0-9] ]
  ```

  the second `[` is run iff the first succeeds (this is how `&&` works), i.e. iff there are exactly two positional parameters. In such case `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2"` and the second test becomes

  ```
  [ "$1" "$2" -eq ^[0-9] ]
  ```

  This doesn't make sense. `[` may complain in different ways depending on actual values of parameters and expansion of `^[0-9]`, still it's garbage.

---

Now about `[[ "$#" = [0-9] ]]`.

<sup>Note: this snippet was in the first revision of the question. The question was edited while I was composing my answer. I decided to keep this fragment because `[[` may be useful eventually anyway.</sup>

- Again: `$#` is always a number.
- `[[` is not equivalent to `[`. Any sane test you can do with `[` you can rewrite with `[[` (although you should't do this mindlessly by jut replacing `[` with `[[`). There are additional tests `[[` can do, it is more powerful. While `[` (and `test`) is required by POSIX, `[[` is not.

  Important thing: `[[` is not a command like `ls` or `[`. It's a keyword, it changes the way the shell parses words that follow. Everything between `[[` and `]]` is parsed differently.

  If the operator is `=`, the next argument is a pattern. Some characters/syntaxes (e.g. `*` or `[0-9]`), when unquoted, are matched against the argument before `=`. It's like filename expansion, but not against existing filenames. Your code tested if (expanded) `$#` is exactly one digit. The whole test was

  ```
  [[ "$#" -eq 2 ]] && [[ "$#" = [0-9] ]]
  ```

  `foo && bar` runs `bar` iff `foo` succeeds. The second `[[` was tested only if `$#` expanded to `2`, so it had to succeed because `2` is exactly one digit. In this case the second `[[` changes nothing.

---

Let's say you realized your mistake and tested if `$1` is a number.

- Like above `[[ "$1" = [0-9] ]]` returns success if `$1` expands to exactly one digit.
- `[[ "$1" = [0-9][0-9] ]]` – exactly two digits.
- `[[ "$1" = [0-9]* ]]` – something that starts with a digit.

To detect any number of digits you need `=~`. This operator inside `[[ ]]` is somewhat similar to `=`, but now the pattern is an extended regular expression. It doesn't need to match the whole string to the left of the operator though, a substring is enough (therefore `^` and `$` anchors are needed in your case):

- `[[ "$1" =~ [0-9] ]]` returns success if `$1` expands to a string containing a digit.
- `[[ "$1" =~ [0-9][0-9] ]]` – … containing two digits next to each other.
- `[[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]$ ]]` – a string that is exactly one digit.
- `[[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]*$ ]]` – zero or more digits.
- `[[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9][0-9]*$ ]]` – one or more digits.
- `[[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]` – one or more digits.

**`[[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]` and `[[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]` are the tests you may want.** To allow leading `-` modify them like this: `[[ "$1" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]`. The whole testing fragment may be

```
[ "$#" -eq 2 ] && `[[ "$1" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]` && `[[ "$2" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]`
```

Inside `[[ ]]` variables/parameters may not be double-quoted and their expanded values will not undergo word splitting and globbing. So you can write `[[ $1 =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]` and it's safe. It's an exception; in general you should double-quote variables. Here double-quoting disturbs nothing, so I advise to quote anyway to get used to this good general practice.

---

You claim you solved the problem using <strike>`[[ "$@" -eq ^[0-9] ]]`. Sorry, I don't believe you. If there are exactly two positional parameters and they are numbers, I don't see a way this can be syntactically correct, let alone test what you want. In other cases… I still don't see a way.</strike>

… using `[[ "$@" =~ ^[0-9] ]]` (from your comment, incoherent with the question). This is not a proper solution. My tests indicate that `"$@"` inside `[[ ]]` behaves like unquoted `$@` treated as one word without word splitting and globbing. This is very similar to how regular variables behave inside `[[ ]]`, although it was not obvious to me in advance, because I know `"$@"` is not like regular variables.

<sup>Side note: for this reason I have never wanted to use `"$@"` inside `[[ ]]`. I cannot imagine a scenario when it's the right thing.</sup>

When there are exactly two positional parameters, your "solution" becomes `[[ "$1 $2" =~ ^[0-9] ]]`. It's syntactically valid and it checks if the very first character of the first argument to your script is a digit. Only this. Run `./scriptgoeshere.sh 0h well`, the arguments will pass the test.

---

Notes:

- `[0-9]` (as globbing pattern or regular expression) depends on your current locale. Most likely it will work as you expect, but technically it's possible to have a locale where `9` precedes `0` or where `2` is beyond `0-9`. The most general way to match against a digit is `[[:digit:]]`. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230/108618).

  On the other hand you may want to use `$1` and/or `$2` with shell arithmetic (`$((…))`), `[ "$1" -ge 50 ]` or such. Then you need Arabic numerals only. Even if `[[:digit:]]` includes them in your locale (it probably does), it may include other digits as well. Consider `[0123456789]`; it is explicit and not locale-dependent.
- Not every string that matches `^-?[0-9]+$` is considered integer from the point of view of `[` and/or `[[` (e.g. when you do `[ "$1" -eq 0 ]`). Each tool has a range of integers it can handle. Similarly shell arithmetic may produce mathematically wrong results if you feed it with a string of digits that describes an out-of-range integer.
- Mathematically `1.00` is an integer. Some tools may accept it as integer, some may not. What about `1e100`?